# Shortest path through coordinates

Tags: shortest-path, plane

I am given a set of point in the `x-y` `plane ={(x1,y1),(x2,y2),.....(xn,yn)}`

and I am given two points `a(xa,ya)` and `b(xb,yb)`
 and asked to find the set of points that cover the shortest path.

no connection between points are given.
If I assume a connection to every other point.it will take a long time to compute these values for a weighted graph. Can someone tell me what reading I should do. what topic does this problem come under graph algorithms?!!(Is there any specific algorithm)
I have been stuck on this for days.
note: need to go through the points. cannot jump across the points.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shortest distance through coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278572/shortest-distance-through-coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

The Shortest path between two points in a plane is a `straight line`. so you could use the points to form the equation of line and check if the set of points satisfies your equation.

Equation of line: `y - y1 = m(x - x1)`

where, `m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`

Comment: but I have to travel through the coordinates. I cant directly reach the other point

Comment: I ain't that dumb -_-

Comment: @DragonSurfer I assume that u have two points and some more set of points? or you need to generate a set of points which traverse through the shortest path between the given points?