# shortest distance through coordinates

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, shortest-path

I am given a set of point in the x-y plane ={(x1,y1),(x2,y2),.....(xn,yn)}

and I am given two points a(xa,ya) and b(xb,yb) and asked to find the set of points that cover the shortest path.

no connection between points are given. If I assume a connection to every other point.it will take a long time to compute these values for a weighted graph. Can someone tell me what reading I should do. what topic does this problem come under graph algorithms?!!(Is there any specific algorithm) I have been stuck on this for days. note: need to go through the points. cannot jump across the points. NO need to travel each and every point in the set. JUST THE POINTS THAT TAKE YOU TO POINT B and the distance covered in doing so should be minimum. ex: { (1,3),(1,4),(1,1),(5,2),(5,3),(1,4),(2,2),(1,2),(1,3)}
and suppose A=(1,1) and B=(1,4) then the path={(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)}
note: paths need not be straight lines.can be zig zag too.

Comment: This falls under the category of [computational geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_geometry) which might help you search around.

Comment: Do you mean the shortest path from `a` to `b` or the shortest path that visits all points starting from `a` and ending in `b`? The former is trivial (just a direct connection) the latter is known as the travelling salesman problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "cover" the shortest path?

Comment: Show us some image examples please

Comment: The long computation you are afraid of is in range n*(n-1)/2 what is acceptable for this kind of problems. Especially when you were not given any complexity level constrains.

Comment: The major question is: what is the real constrain of going from a to b? It is not just a -> b (absolute shortest path), but is it passing all points, passing a minimum number of points, passing points that are close enough to a-b (like crossing a map where points are like crossroads), something else?  Without information on the constrains, the question makes little sense.

Comment: The solution to this depends entirely on what "the set of points that cover the shortest path" means.

Comment: you don't need to go through all the points. just the points that will take you to point b.the point have to be chosen such that the distance covered is minimum.

Comment: So, are you just trying to find all the points that lie on the straight line between a and b?

Comment: @DragonSurfer so how far can we jump at most? For example could I reach `(5 , 3)` from `(1 , 3)` in your example? Can I switch direction somewhere in between or only at points? Is this just some sort of connect the dots-problem?

Comment: cannot jump more than 2 units

Comment: @DragonSurfer not exactly a precise question, but I tried my best to provide a answer.

Comment: @DragonSurfer: *"cannot jump more than 2 units*". The fact that there is a maximum distance between to visited points is the crucial piece of infromation that is missing from your question. Next time try to write down a complete problem statement from the beginning and you might get usefull answers

Comment: The difficult part is still the there is no fixed constrained at this moment.  The shortest path is still a straight line between a and b, possibly containing some points of the given set.  What does "jump across the points" mean geometrically?  A reasonable constrain could be "the path can't intersect with any lines between the points of the set". That would mean that we still have 1 straight line if all the points are on one side of the path.

Comment: think of a river. with floating rocks. you can only jump a distance of 2 units. you are very lazy so you want to cross the river in least time.the coordinates of the rocks are given. geometrically jumping across the entire river makes sense since its the minimum distance. but I ain't marvels hulk character. the point A can be considered as the one side of the shore and point B the other side.

Comment: So the constrain is that the maximum distance of moving from 1 point to another is 2.  Is the distance calculated in all directions using floating point, in the 4 main directions or in the 8 directions (including diagonals)?  The river analogy suggests all directions, but the small integer parameters suggest 4 or 8 directions. Anyway, it is a matter of finding the unvisited points that can be visited and backtracking as shown here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/254223/looking-for-an-algorithm-to-connect-dots-shortest-route

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shortest path through coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275776/shortest-path-through-coordinates)

Answer (score 1):

Probably a more formal definition of "jumping across the points" is crucial to solve this problem. You may start with calculating distances for edges not violating the rule of not jumping. Next process the graph with Dijkstra algorithm or A*. Just first find how to mathematically identify valid edges.

Answer (score 1):

Since we can move at most two distance-units at a time, we can easily implement a DFS-traversal using sets and simply guessing whether points exist, since we have to guess for at most 8 points per point:

```
input: set points //a set of points that are placed on the grid
       point a
       point b
output: list path //a list of points, from a to b

map predecessor
predecessor.put(a , null)

set visited
visited.add(a)

//stores pairs consisting of (distance traveled , point)
//ordered ascending by distance to a
sortedset tovisit(sortyBy(pair::first , comparison::ascending)) 
tovisit.add(pair(0 , a))

//flag to check, if path was found
bool pathFound = false

while !tovisit.isEmpty()
    pair search = tovisit.remove(0)
    int dist = search.first()
    point pt = search.second()

    //check if we reached the end of the path
    if pt == b
        pathFound = true
        break

    //check if a point exists down from the current point
    //with a distance of at most 2 units that hasn't been visited
    point next = point(pt.x , pt.y + 1)
    if points.contains(next)
        if !visited.contains(next)
            predecessor.put(next , a)
            tovisit.add(pair(dist + 1 , next)
    else if points.contains(point(next.x , next.y + 1)
        next = point(pt.x , pt.y + 2)
        if !visited.contains(next)
            predecessor.put(next , a)
            tovisit.add(pair(dist + 2 , next)

    //proceed for other directions
    //...    

//build path
if !pathFound
    return null

list path
node tmp = b
do
    path.prepend(tmp)
    tmp = predecessor.get(tmp)
while tmp != null

return path
```

This code utilizes the fact, that we can only traverse at most 2 units in each direction, thus leaving us with at most 8 directions to check.

If this isn't given, we have to at first build a data-structure representing the grid. A simple solution would be to build a grid in which each point is connected to it's direct neighbors (worst case `O(n ^ 2)`) and traversing this grid with DFS.